# Post image from local bundle to PinInterest iphone.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, post, uiimage

I have implemented the PinInterest through web view using this code:

```
NSString *description = @"Post your description here";
NSURL* sUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-w4oTZjlpgwo/T5_pi-KJPuI/AAAAAAAAAoM/rKm3E0XCbgY/s1600/red_rose_flower3.jpg"];// pass your link here with your image name

// NSLog(@"URL:%@", sUrl);
NSString *protectedUrl = ( NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,( CFStringRef)sUrl, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)));
NSLog(@"Protected URL:%@", protectedUrl);
NSString *imageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"", sUrl];

imageUrl=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:mAppDelegate.imagename ofType:nil];

NSString *buttonUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=www.flor.com&media=%@&description=%@\"", protectedUrl, description];

NSMutableString *htmlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:1000];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"<html> <body>"];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"<p align=\"center\"><a href=%@ class=\"pin-it-button\" count-layout=\"horizontal\"><img border=\"0\" src=\"http://assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png\" title=\"Pin It\" /></a></p>", buttonUrl];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"<p align=\"center\"><img width=\"300px\" height = \"400px\" src=%@></img></p>", imageUrl];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js\"></script>"];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"</body> </html>"];
return htmlString;
```

And I have also tried using PinInterest iOS SDK, but all I found is that can only pin the image from url.

And I need to pin image from local bundle image.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the document once, they said Right now, "we only support pinning an image from a url. In the future, we’ll add support for pinning local images." i think this answers your question. for more clarification reed [this](http://developers.pinterest.com/ios/). hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for answer, but can i upload the pics to my dropbox and google drive and give the link url to post, will apple allow that..?

Comment: yeah, but i am scaring of ,if mine app will get reject because of this from apple..